# Jetty 9 with lz4 compression

Tags: java, embedded-jetty, jetty-9, http-compression, lz4

At this moment I have embedded Jetty 9 with default gzip compression that can handle 65MB worth of text data compressed into 4.6MB. This is very fast when the data is given all at once. However the performance degrades so much when the text data is given as stream.

I'm trying to find alternative compression algorithm that can be plugged into Jetty 9 that can speed up the compression. I'm looking for LZ4 compression described in [here](http://java-performance.info/performance-general-compression/) and wondering how I can plug into Jetty 9.

Comment: Is the text data static?  If so, precompress it before you start jetty.  Jetty will just serve the compressed format (gzip or brotli) atm.

Comment: @JoakimErdfelt the text data is not static. It is json data

Comment: Any luck on this one? I am hit by the same problem and gzip is not working very well.

Comment: @dcg Not on using lz4 compression. I changed from using `response.getOutputStream()` to `response.getWritter' and now I get pretty decent performance.